# Windows 7 guest on Mac 10.10 host VMwareFusion USB Drivers not installing

Tags: windows-7, drivers, vmware-fusion, usb-3, osx-yosemite

I have a MacBook Pro 13" mid 2012 model running OSX 10.10 yosemite which has two USB 3.0 ports on it. I have VMwareFusion installed, and have windows 7 as a guest operating system.

The driver for the USB controller is not installing, so I cannot use any USB devices. I tried clicking "Update Driver" and then "Search automatically for updated driver software" and it did not work. In the device manager window, it shows a yellow triangle with an exclamation point in it beside the USB controller device.

I really need to be able to to use USB devices with the windows 7 guest. How can I get it to work?

Below is a screenshot of the virtual machine, showing the USB controller device.

[image: Screenshot]

Below is a screenshot of the system information app on my mac showing information about the USB hardware
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VMware workstations on Mac do not support USB 3 for Windows 7. A lot of excuses which amount to nothing but "we don't want to spend money to develop it". They just don't and won't do it. Upgrade to Windows 8 is the common answer.  Or get Parallels which support USB 3 on Windows 7 for long time just proving the point that Vmware excuses are just that, excuses. Now that Windows 10 is here, Vmware will expect you to migrate to Win 10 as a solution. Another non-sense. Most users intend to stay with Win 7 for at least another year, as Win 10 upgrade is full of pitfalls.

Comment: Please remove the opinion based parts of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple:

Windows 7 haven't native(build in) support for USB 3.0. and drivers are provided by manufacturers, VMware will not make developement to each vendor, support only will work if guest OS provide native support.

[PC World Article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/238660/microsoft_throws_support_behind_usb_3_0_with_windows_8.html)

[Blog (Building a Robust USB 3.0 Support)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2011/08/22/building-robust-usb-3-0-support.aspx)